# How do I extract inner rectangle from a binary image of nested rectangles?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to localize an LCD in a set of images but currently stuck at a certain point in the process. This is the binary image of a region of interest, how do I extract the inner rectangle from this -- or coordinates of the inside corner of the boundaries.

[image: binary image of LCD]

I tried the following,
Find edges in the image using `Canny()`, use `findContours()` to find contours. From a list of contours, I run into two problems,

1. Which contour to select?
2. From this image, I got more than 10 contours and only the outside rectangle is a complete rectangle. Rest all contours are disjoint lines that together make the inside rectangle

This is my code,

```
// threshold
Mat im1_thresh;
threshold(im1, im1_thresh, 100, 200, THRESH_BINARY);        

// find edges
Mat im1_canny;
Canny(im1_thresh, im1_canny, 50, 100);

// find contours
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(im1_canny, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

// draw contours
RNG rng;
vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
Mat im1_contours = Mat::zeros(im1_thresh.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    // draw each contour in a different color
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(im1_contours, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());

    // draw bounding boxes around each contour in original image
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours[i]));
    rectangle(im1, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
}
```

*Question*: How do I localize the inner rectangle from the above binary image?

Comment: Can you simply shrink the outer contour to use as the inner? Alternately cv::erode the line before making the contour so it is a single thin line and inner and outer are the same

Comment: @MartinBeckett I get the outer contour using `RETR_EXTERNAL` parameter in `findContours()` but I cannot use it because the thinkness of line in the image keeps changing in the images from my dataset. Erosion will also impact the accuracy of the resultant contour. I believe I can use `hierarchy` of contours here to find a solution but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of disjoint contours -- I adjusted the threshold value until the contour was smooth. Blurring also helps sometimes. After that, I select the innermost contour.

I used the `hierarchy` array in the code above to select the relevant contour and create a bounding box using it on the original image. The hierarchy array is an N*4 matrix where N is the number of contours. For each contour, `hierarchy` contains information on related contours as `[previous, next, child, parent]`. You can see the value `-1` if there is no related contour.

This is the hierarchy matrix for the image in question,

> [-1,-1,1,-1]
>   [-1,-1,2,0]
>   [-1,-1,3,1]
>   [-1,-1,-1,2]

I am interested in the last contour. It is childless and has `2` as parent.
This is my implementation,

```
Rect boundRect;

// loop through the contours/hierarchy
for (int i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
    // hierarchy is (previous, next, child, parent)
    // look for innermost -- no child but a parent exists
    if (hierarchy[i][2] == -1 && hierarchy[i][3] != -1) {
        // draw contour
        Scalar color = Scalar(255,0,0);
        drawContours(im1_contours, contours, i, color);

        // draw a bounding rectangle around original image
        boundRect = boundingRect(Mat(contours[i]));
        rectangle(im1, boundRect.tl(), boundRect.br(), color);
    }
}

// subset the image
Mat im1_roi;
im1_roi = im1(boundRect);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the most rectangular contour, you could run `minAreaRect` to fit a rotated rectangle, then compare the result to the original contour.

The ratio of areas of each might be enough, depending on noise etc.

Once you select the most rectangular contour, using `approxPoly` to reduce to 4 points should give you a good approximation of the screen rectangle.

Comment: I ran into another issue last night that if there is a dead pixel on the screen, it also shows up in the list of contours. Then the assertion fails that screen is the minimum area rectangle. I am currently using `contourArea()` and values from trial and error to find the appropriate rectangle

Answer (score 0):

> From this image, I got more than 10 contours and only the outside rectangle is a complete rectangle. Rest all contours are disjoint lines that together make the inside rectangle

You are using the default Canny apertureSize = 3, try to increase it to 5 or 7 and it will detect the inner contour as one instead of multiple small contours. Try this:

```
int apertureSize = 5;
Canny(im1_thresh, im1_canny, 50, 100, apertureSize);
```

> I ran into another issue last night that if there is a dead pixel on the screen, it also shows up in the list of contours.

Check the area of each contour to make sure it is larger than the minimum acceptable area. The size of the picture that you provided is 250x450, and the inner rectangle size is ~170x380. So you may set the minArea as 80% of 170x380 (= 0.8 * 64600). For instance, add this check to the loop before drawing.

```
float minArea = 0.8 * 64600;   
if (boundRect[i].area() > minArea ){
    rectangle(im1, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
}
```